# LiDAR GUI tool for selecting and saving groups of points?

Tags: clip, lidar, gui, las

I'm working in a small group that is processing LiDAR data with some custom code. We need to see how well our stuff is working so we need samples of "truth" data that we can compare our output against.

Ideally we could load a .las file into a Graphical User Interface (GUI) then select a series or group of points that can be saved off. Then, we could programmatically compare the output to the truth.

We will have thousands of point groups to manually save so I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do so.

Comment: We need a human to sit in front of a GUI loaded with lidar point data so that they can select series/groups of points with a mouse, which can be saved to the file system.  This data will then be compared against the output of algorithms that we developed to detect certain objects in the lidar point cloud.  This is how we will determine the accuracy of the algorithms on large sets of test data.  Just need an easy way to create this truth data on large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (or fortunately), I just know a commercial software to do that. It is TNT Mips Pro (Terrain / LiDAR Manager). First, you have to do an interactive edition of point classes, and then extract the points by areas or by class. Both steps can be guided through: http://www.microimages.com/documentation/TechGuides/76lidarReclassify.pdf and http://www.microimages.com/documentation/TechGuides/78LASextract.pdf.

Tip: Always keep the original las cloud stored safely. Never work over the original!

I have not used this software by myself, but I saw it in a live demonstration. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is gui tools for quickly manipulating/filtering lidar points. [LasTools](http://rapidlasso.com) created by Martin Isenburg provide a set of programs to do such task.

For clipping/filtering voxels you can use lasclip or lasview, screenshots on website.

lastools have also object recognition using lasground, lasclassify for buildings and vegetation.

You can find some lidar data in the original web page of lastools:
http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/

Ex: lidar data of Gilmer
http://www.wvview.org/data/lidar/Gilmer/las/